# Program in C, Read and Write

Tags: c, character, buffer

This is a simple program to read the the text in **secret.in** and write it in **secret.out**
but I have a question. I need to know what exactly the purpose from the line **20** to **24**?
I tried to write more than 128 letters and numbers but it didn't show up to me **Characters found, c=**
Can someone tell me why?

```
#include <fcntl.h>   // open
#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit
#include <unistd.h> 
#define N_BUFFER 1
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[N_BUFFER], c;
    int in, out;
    int nread = N_BUFFER;
    int i;
    c = '\0';
    if (argc > 1) c = argv[1][0];
    in = open("secret.in", O_RDONLY);
    out = open("secret.out", O_WRONLY);

    while (nread == N_BUFFER) {
        nread = read(in, buffer, 128);
        for (i = 0; i < nread; i++) {    // line 20
            if (c == buffer[i] && argc > 0)
                printf(" Characters found, c= %d\n", c);
        }                                // line 24
        write(out, buffer, nread);
    }
    close(in);
    close(out);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: One detail: `argc > 0` is constant in the loop (lines 20-24). Perhaps moving that condition to enclose the loop - or remove it completely, would make it clearer?

Comment: `#include <fcntl.h>   // open`, `fcntl` is needed for `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY`, you need to `include <unistd.h>` for `open()`

Comment: You are defining a 1(`N_BUFFER`) length buffer but saying the `read` function that your buffer's length is greater or equal to 128 bytes.  You should change 128 with N_BUFFER.

Comment: The message " Characters found..." is printed once for each byte of the input that's successfully read and that's equal to the first character of the first command-line argument to the binary (or 0 if there's no command-line arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The read function returns the number of bytes read. So for more than 128 characters your call to the read function will return a value of 128, then the next time the while loop is evaluated the value of `nread` will be 128 which will not equal `N_BUFFER` so the loop will terminate.

It may be more beneficial to check that that `nread` is greater than 0 (read will return a value of 0 for end of file).